# Programatically getting USB power draw of a device?

Tags: windows, linux, usb

In Windows, it is possible to view a Power tab for a USB hub in Device Manager that lists  information such as whether the hub is self-powered and the total power available.

Is this information available programatically, either in Windows (perhaps WMI?) or Linux? I've looked in MSDN with little success so far.

Answer (score 4):

Linux:

lsusb -v | grep MaxPower

Comment: I think this just shows the maximum amount that can be drawn, not what's being drawn by a particular device. http://superuser.com/questions/297959/how-do-you-check-how-much-power-a-usb-port-can-deliver

Answer (score 2):

I think WMI is going to be your best bet here.  I'm not familar with exactly what you want, but I'd start with the [Win32_VoltageProbe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394514(VS.85).aspx) class.

Comment: There's also Win32_CurrentProbe, which would be more relevant since the voltage should always be 5V for USB.
The easiest way to use this is to use this PowerShell command: `Get-WmiObject -class Win32_CurrentProbe` or `Get-WmiObject -class Win32_VoltageProbe`. However, both of these return no results on my system, so maybe CurrentProbe and VoltageProbe compatible USB hosts & hubs might be rare.